# Migrate data from mongodb to hdfs

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

i am new to data engineering. I am trying to setup the environment for big data project. As of now, I have installed hadoop, mongodb, hive, and spark. Right now i want to try a simulation to see the interaction between mongodb and hadoop. I already have data in my mongodb. So i want to migrate the data into hadoop hdfs. is it possible? I read a lot of explanation about it but did not understand the idea of the migration. Can anyone please explain in a simple way on how to do it? because i am a total beginner in this field.

Comment: Hive and Spark can connect directly to Mongo. Do you really need to "migrate"? Surely a mongo query would be faster than reading Hadoop

Comment: ohh really? because i thought hadoop is essential if i want to do a bigdata project. I plan to use the hdfs for storage. Mind suggesting me any reference to tackle bigdata project?

Comment: Unfortunately asking for such things is off topic for Stackoverflow. And no, you don't need Hadoop/HDFS to use Spark or Hive

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have data in Mongo, I would suggest using [SparkSQL with Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/java/datasets-and-sql/) to load in a DataFrame object of your collection, let's call it `df`.

e.g.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
  .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
  .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
  .getOrCreate();

// Create a JavaSparkContext using the SparkSession's SparkContext object
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

// Load data and infer schema, disregard toDF() name as it returns Dataset
Dataset<Row> df = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
```

Then you can write out the data into either HDFS or Hive using [`df.write.save`, which defaults to parquet output format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html), or `df.write.saveAsTable` (for Spark Hive tables) or `df.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE ...)` (raw Hive tables). Ref - [SparkSQL Hive docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html)

---

Note: This is a one-time load... If you want to stream all inserts and changes out of Mongo to Hadoop, you could use Debezium w/ Kafka, for example, then use the Debezium cluster to also run a HDFS Kafka Connect Sink (which has Hive integration)

Comment: Isn't the question about moving data from hdfs to Mongo! Your answer seems to be doing the converse of that.

Comment: Why do both the input and output uri's , i.e. 'mongodb.input.uri' and 'mongodb.output.uri', point to Mongo!!

Comment: @KG This question is about reading from Mongo. The config options are if you did want to read+write, and was copied from the documentation